# Para que usar Docker para programar?

Tags: docker

Usar um container Docker para um banco de dados é fácil de entender a necessidade, pois não preciso instalar nada na minha máquina, fica tudo no container. Mas o que eu não entendo é qual a vantagem de usar um container Docker para programar?

Por exemplo: Se for criar uma app em Node eu teria que instalar todos os pacotes localmente (se não o VS Code não vai reconhecer os imports) e depois criar um volume para jogar tudo no container.

Ora, se eu tenho que ter tudo local, para que ter um container? Não vai aumentar o processamento da minha máquina?

Não ficaria mais leve para minha máquina rodar o app direto nela e o container só para banco de dados?

Obrigado!

Comment: Pra quem faz coisas simples não precisa. E por simples não estou falando de coisas bobas. um ERP completo pode ser simples nesse conceito que estou fazendo. Docker é usado mais onde a pessoa vai adicionando complexidade, quase sempre desnecessárias, o que ele por si só já é complexidade desnecessária. Não estou dizendo que ele não seja útil, mas é bem menos do que as pessoas acham. Não que seja errado sempre, mas eu diria o mesmo para o DB.

Comment: No caso do banco de dados, as vezes eu não quero ficar instalando, ainda mais se quiser ter o MySQL, Mongo, Postgree, acho até justificável. Mas para programar com o Node não vejo como fugir de instalar ele. Por isso não entendo mesmo a necessidade.

Comment: @WebDevBrazil não tem necessidade mesmo. Até em produção muita gente usa pq viu o blogueiro favorito dizer que era bom. Container é mais eficiente do que várias VMs na mesma máquina, mas a maior parte das aplicações não precisa de separação, pra começo de conversa. O cara faz site de lojinha e acha que com container se preparou para virar "amazon", em vez de focar em aprender a programar, e entender um pouquinho de infra antes de pegar o primeiro serviço. No seu exemplo, não precisa de container para base de dados nem nada. Mesmo se for rodar 10 instâncias de DB separadas não precisa disso.

Comment: Um dos *"supostos"* motivo é que muitos devs que fazem as coisas sem saber o que estão fazendo (acredite é possível e comum) tinham como desculpa: "no meu computador funcionava", então com Docker é "levado" o ambiente para outros lugares, ou seja, uma das ideias era não sofrerem com complexidade de publicar um ambiente, só que na prática isso não é tão simples, compensaria mais a pessoa aprender melhor a fazer as coisas e preparar um pré-ambiente isolado no servidor para subir o sistema (com banco de dados alternativo), mas isso é outra história. Como eu disse, é um dos supostos motivos.

Comment: Ainda, um MySQL em ambiente de desenvolvimento por exemplo: você com uma instalação só (ou mera cópia de executável, sem instalar) pode rodar um monte de instância (e só roda cada uma quando for usar, via atalho) direto do desktop, apenas criando atalhos diferentes para cada aplicação (mudando o IP, por ex 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, etc e pasta de armazenamento), e ter separação total das bases para desenvolvimento. E o melhor, só executa quando estiver desenvolvendo. Coisas do dia a dia que facilitam muito mais o trabalho usando o básico do básico do que já vem "de fábrica" no OS e no engine.

Comment: Pessoal obrigado! As suas respostas em conjunto tiraram a minha dúvida! Não precisa mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos motivos de se usar container, você já deu. Recursos adicionais.

Para desenvolver você ganha por estar no ambiente mais próximo ao produtivo. Onde **você consegue lidar com** as mesmas configurações e principalmente, **as mesmas dependências**.

Sempre que sua aplicação depende de algo que não é apenas um pacote (NPM, nuget, maven), ou seja, depende de alguma instalação no ambiente de desenvolvimento, seja com apt ou apk ou de outra forma qualquer, você terá dificuldades em lidar com grandes times, com diversos projetos e diversos tipos diferentes de dependências.

Um exemplo disso é o uso de DB2 com .NET Core no Linux. Pacotes Windows e Linux são diferentes, dependem de versão específica do java, variáveis de ambiente compatíveis com o setup, influenciam no perfil de build.

Ou quando você precisa de algo como tesseract, ffmpeg e afins.

Se você tem algo mais complexo, como diversos projetos que precisam conversar também há facilidades.

Se você tem uma api node vanilla, essas dificuldades não existem, mas se você está em um ecossistema que leve docker a sério, faz sentido por padronização, mesmo que você faça pouco uso desses benefícios. Mas fique atento, muitas vezes monitoramento depende de setup na máquina e esse é também um típico caso em que mesmo sem a aplicação diretamente depender de nada que envolva docker. Algo importante depende.

As dependências do seu vscode, só dizem respeito a ele. Isso não entra no assunto docker.

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta. Eu só falei do VSCode, por que vejo falarem do docker para não instalar dependencias na máquina, e depois eles só instalam o node no container, o que dá a entender que a dependencia é o node e os pacotes npm. E se fosse só isso, não tem vantagem pois temos que instalar na máquina tudo isso localmente. Mas depois da sua explicação, ficou mais claro as coisas.

Comment: @AgênciaEffetivo a questão não é não instalar na máquina, é não depender de algo que só exista nela. Essa é a sacada. Se você inadvertidamente instala alguma coisa para o projeto A, você garante que um projeto B não leva código que dependa de algo que não existe no contexto dele, mas na sua máquina existe.